# running setup:upgrade causes an error from a disabled module

Tags: magento2, third-party-module, exception

When I run `bin/magento setup:upgrade` I get this error:

```
Source class "\WeltPixel\Backend\Model" for "WeltPixel\Backend\Model\Logger" generation does not exist.

[RuntimeException]
Source class "\WeltPixel\Backend\Model" for "WeltPixel\Backend\Model\Logger" generation does not exist.
```

We have recently uninstalled the Pearl theme from Weltpixel and all of their modules (including Backend).  Why would magento (2.2.4) still call the Weltpixel backend after it has been disabled using the `bin/magento module:disable` command?  Is there anything I can do to recover this?

Comment: Just delete /var/generation folder /pub/static folder except(.htaccess) file @user68323 and then try yo run upgrade command.

Comment: @Learing_Coder did not find a `var/generation` folder, I did delete `pub/static` and ran the `setup:upgrade` again, but I get the same error.

Comment: generation folder will be in root folder delete(except .htaccess) @user68323

Comment: Hi @user68323 did u get any solution for this? i am also facing same issue can you guide me

Answer (score 0):

You can regenrate the classes in generation by running following command ;

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

Don't forget to give permission after running the command;

```
sudo chmod 777 -R var pub generation
```

Comment: I ran the `setup:di:compile` command, but I get this output:


  `[RuntimeException]
  Source class "\WeltPixel\Backend\Model" for "WeltPixel\Backend\Model\Logger" generation does not exist.


setup:di:compile`

Comment: @Vivek Kumar i have followed your setps but no luck any idea?

Answer (score 0):

From root Magento directory, run rm -rf var/cache/* to solve the problem.